# Map Area, Controller and Action names to default values if empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am given 3 strings: `area`, `controller` and `action`. Some of them could have empty values, as there are default values defined in my routes. For example, if `action` is empty it will be mapped to `Index`.

I wish to pass these 3 strings through the routing of my application and get their actual values after any empty values where mapped to default values. Is this possible?

Maybe it is doable by doing something like this

```
RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(context)
```

but is there a way to do it without constructing a whole `HttpContext` object?

Comment: Panos, I attempted to answer your questions below.  If you could provide some more context about why you are trying to do something like this and why you need to do it, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will have to do is take your three strings and convert that into a URL that can be passed thru the routing system.  How you do this depends upon what routes you have created.  Let's assume you have the typical default route in your route table:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then you would have to use the URL pattern  "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}" to build up your URL. In your case, some of the strings could be empty, so your URL would not have all of the segments.  For example, if Area="Admin" and Controller and Action are empty, your URL, based on this route, would be:

```
~/Admin
```

Of course, this raises the question of if you already know the routes in your system, why can't you just get the defaults by looking at the routes.

Once you have the URL that you want to test, you will need to create a mock of the HttpContentBase object and then run it thru RouteTable.Routes.GetDate(httpContext).  There is straightforward boiler plate code to do this, since you really do not need to mock much of the constituent HttpRequestBase or HttpResponseBase classes.  For example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228179/mocking-httpcontextbase-with-moq) for an example of mocking an HttpContextBase object using the Moq mocking framework.