# How to Mock out Response.Cookies.Add() in Moq?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, cookies, nunit, moq

I have an asp.net mvc 3 project which has in one of my controllers

```
Response.Cookies.Add()
```

When I run some old unit tests they now die on "Response" as it is null. I am not sure how to mock it up to solve this problem.

I seen a couple posts here but none of the solutions seems to work and none talk about "Cookies".

Answer (score 2):

```
var responseCookies = new HttpCookieCollection();
var mockResponse = Mock.Of<HttpResponseBase>(r => r.Cookies == responseCookies);
//you can use new Mock<>, and the set it up as well, but for simple setups I prefer the above syntax

myTestController.Response = mockResponse;
```

Comment: The `Response` property is read-only. You need to mock the `ControllerContext ` instead. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18101855/5844190)

Answer (score 1):

Create class e.g. `ResponseProvider` which cover this static functionality. In code, you add this class as next dependency and than will call e.g. `responseProvider.AddCookie()`. In tests, you can use mock object for this `ResponseProvider`.