# Why am I getting the following error: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when I run a Unit Test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, nullreferenceexception

I have never run Unit testing before and I am just trying to run an example I have found on the net over and over in regards to the view name.

My Test code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Admin.Web.API.Controllers;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Admin.Web.API.Controllers.Tests
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class HomeControllerTests
    {
        [TestMethod()]
        public void IndexTest()
        {
            HomeController controller = new HomeController();
            var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
            Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the Line that sets the view result.

What do I need to do to get this working? Is there anything out there that is more descriptive as to Unit testing examples?

**Edit one**

**Controller Code for Index**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (this.Session["UserID"] == null)
    {
        return View("Login");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        ViewBag.SiteID = this.Session["SiteID"];
        ViewBag.AssemblyVersion = this.Session["AssemblyVersion"];
        ViewBag.UserFirstName = this.Session["FirstName"];
        GoogleAnalytics _oGoogleAnalytics = new GoogleAnalytics();
        ViewBag.GoogleAnalytics = _oGoogleAnalytics.GetGoogleAnalytics(
            this.Session["GoogleAnalyticsAccountCode"].ToString(),
            Convert.ToBoolean(this.Session["UseGoogleAnalytics"]));
            return View("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  Seriously, can we stop with this duplicate crap on these kinds of questions?  I'm sure the OP knows something is null, but not how to fix the test, which in this case is to provide a ControllerContext to give the controller the needed info.  The problem here isn't he doesn't know what a NRE is, its that he doesn't know how to setup the controller properly for unit testing because MVC normally handles that.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was giving all that information in my answer when you decided to close this all on your own.  The question has all the details needed for someone familiar with the relevant technologies to answer.

Comment: @Andy OP's problem was completely unrelated to the post according to comment... Don't forget to align question to your future answer when you are done.

Comment: Could you revise your line about where the error was? I read it as meaning the Assert line since you mention view and result. It might help to comment on the line that failed to be perfectly clear.

Comment: @Guvante... pukes on the `controller.index` line

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not sure what you mean the problem was unrelated to the post?

Comment: John, I think my answer will help.

Comment: @Andy: OP's post - "getting NRE in unit test", actual issue "no idea that server is not running during unit test" (with whole bunch of side issues like not being able to debug code and picking most complicated method for first ever unit test and generally lack of good practices in controller). Your good answer mostly  address NRE and not how to write tests for MVC code (really mostly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228179/mocking-httpcontextbase-with-moq, but ...)

Comment: @Andy you have not edited title of this post...nor tags - please consider doing so.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This is a common issue when people start unit testing their MVC code; yes the other question is similar, but that poster already knew he needed to supply the controller with information normally done when running under Asp.Net.  Unfortunately for others the reason for the controller missing information is non-obvious and they aren't expecting a NRE, so this question will hopefully serve to connect the dots between the NRE and how to fix it.  That said, what exactly do you suggest for edits without losing the path from problem to solution?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the controllers `Session` property, which will be null because you haven't supplied the controller with the information it needs to create it.  This information is normally supplied automatically when running under the Asp.Net pipeline.  You can verify this by debugging and stepping into (F11) the `Index` action method and hovering over `Session`.

You need to set the [ControllerContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext(v=vs.118).aspx) property of the controller.  Even better would be to use the [Authorize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute on your action method / controller.  [This](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs) is a good post about how to do Forms authentication in MVC.

The simplest way to get your test going though is to use the `Controller`'s `User` property.  You also do this by creating an instance of `ControllerContext` and setting its `HttpContext` property, probably by Moq'ing [HttpContextBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase(v=vs.110).aspx) so that you can return whatever `IPrincipal` you want.

So this is what you'd need to add after you new up your controller (I'm showing you with the [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) framework, but the VS UnitTest tools might provide its own way to do mocks.  Either is fine):

```
var principalMock = new Mock<IPrincipal>(); // Mock<T> is from the Moq framework
principalMock.Setup(x => x.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true); // Or false, depending on what you're testing

var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(principalMock.Object);

var controllerContext = new ControllerContext { HttpContext = contextMock.Object };
conrollerContext.Controller = controller;
controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
```

After you have all that setup, then you can safely call the action method you're testing.

Answer (score 0):

`controller.Index()` is not returning a `ViewResult` and thus `result` is `null`.

`result.ViewName` is then failing as you are dereferencing `null`.

You need to look at the definition of `Index` and determine what type of object it is returning. Alternatively you can create a variable for `controller.Index()` and see what type it has.

EDIT:

Taking a deeper look at `Index()` it appears that you are relying on some data points that might not be available. The controller is relying on its framework (in this case your test framework) to provide certain pieces, IIRC the `Session` and `ViewBag` are two of those pieces.

Comment: Like I said, I am new to the whole Unit Testing scheme. How do I do that? What do you mean by definition of Index. Are you talking about the controller code for the ActionResult? I'll edit the question and add the Controller code for Index if that helps.

Comment: @JohnSchultz This issue isn't really related to unit testing at all. Either the method 'Index' on the HomeController class is returning null, or its return type is not ViewResult

Comment: OK, I commented out everything except the return view and the title and now it works. How am I supposed to do any tests if I cannot determin what page Im on?

Comment: `Index()` *is* returning a `ViewResult`.  I think the more likely explanation (given the new code posted) is that `Session` or `ViewBag` is null.

Comment: @JohnSchultz: What do you mean by determining what page you're on?  When you run a unit test, there is no web server, so things like `Session` and `ViewBag` may not be initialized.

Comment: The error is happening when he tries to use the controllers Session property, because he hasn't supplied anything to populate it.