# Populating a fake HttpContext.Current.Application in System.Web.Services.WebService

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, mocking, httpcontext

We're trying to create unit tests for an old .NET 4 web service. An MCVE:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://somecompany.com/someservice/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class RealService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private readonly int _key;

    public RealService()
    {
        _key = (int)Application["appKey"];
    }
}
```

This of course crashes because `Application` is null. It seems `Application` is an instance of `System.Web.HttpApplicationState` provided by IIS. We need to run this in MSTest, not IIS.

Fortunately, Vadim Zozulya's [`FakeHttpContext`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FakeHttpContext/) provides a fake `HttpContext`, including `HttpApplicationState`:

```
using (new FakeHttpContext.FakeHttpContext())
{
    HttpContext.Current.Application["appKey"] = 1831423222;
    var rs = new RealService();
    rs.ServiceToTest(testData);
}
```

While this creates an `Application` instance inside `RealService`, it does not set the `HttpApplicationState`; `Application.Count` is zero and `Application["appKey"]` is null.

I consulted [Mocking HttpContext.Current.Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937377/) and the accepted answer also has no effect:

```
 (new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))["appKey"] = 1831423222;
```

also does not add `Application["appKey"]`. How do I populate a fake `HttpContext.Current.Application` in `System.Web.Services.WebService`?

Comment: You say that FakeHttpContext provides an HttpApplicationState, and indeed it's not null. But it doesn't seem to retain values. I looked through FakeHttpContext's code and didn't see anything special for dealing with the Application property. I imagine we'd have to dig into the System.Web code to see why it doesn't retain values put into it. I tried setting the Application property to a new HttpApplicationState but the property is readonly, and even using reflection I was struggling to figure out how to set a value. Interesting problem!

Comment: Thanks for investigating @mason. I investigated the Production servers, and each install has a Global.asax file with `protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) { Application["appKey"] = differentNumberOnEachServer; }`

Comment: I've been poking around the framework source code and I can't seem to find any explanation for why it doesn't retain values once set. I know this is a bit of a cop out, but perhaps you could just not use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application to store data, and instead create a public property in your HttpApplication class (Global.asax) or perhaps some static class? That way you wouldn't be tied to the internals of System.Web.

Comment: [System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Web/HttpContext.cs#L781) just returns the static property [HttpApplicationFactory.ApplicationState](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Web/HttpApplicationFactory.cs#L641). That returns a private field's value (_state). I assume that _state's value is getting overwritten or not persisted. But without attaching debugger to framework source code that's about as far as I can get.