# HttpContext is "null" during MSTest execution

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, httpcontext

For my program, it requires httpContext to be present, but, during MSTest, the values is set to "null".

Is there any way to provide the value to httpContext?

Comment: HttpContext is provided by the host, like IIS. MSTest does not provide one so you have to [create a fake HttpContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71345380/populating-a-fake-httpcontext-current-application-in-system-web-services-webserv).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying various methods, and the working method, without changes to the main controller was this:

```
public void Test_Method()
{
 var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(); var stream = new
 MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(""));           
 httpContext.Request.Body = stream; httpContext.Request.ContentLength =
 stream.Length; ControllerName controller = new() {
        ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
        {
         HttpContext = httpContext
        } };
}
```

Add the additional namespace packages:

```
using System.IO; 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Text;
```