# Sitecoe WebUtil.SessionValue Unit Testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, sitecore

I am trying to unit test following code

```
var test = WebUtil.GetSessionValue("test") as ViewResult;
```

And I have setup my test like this:

```
var session = new Moq.Mock<WebUtil>();
session.SetUp(s => s.GetSessionValue).Returns();
```

I am having a hard time mocking WebUtil and set up value for GetSessionValue

Comment: So ,what is your problem? Do you get any error? Use Returns  method as what you want to return session like `.Returns("foo")`;

Comment: I am having problem s= >s.GetSessionValue, It does not allow me and throw error there

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mock `WebUtil` static methods. You need an [abstraction](https://medium.com/@martinrybak/how-to-mock-singletons-and-static-methods-in-unit-tests-cbe915933c7d#721d) but in this particular case introducing smth like `IWebUtil` may look too awkward.

A better solution would be to use an overloaded version of the `GetSessionValue` method which receives `HttpContextBase` as a parameter:

```
public static object GetSessionValue(string key, HttpContextBase context) { ... }
```

The `HttpContextBase` is a new well mockable version of the old static HTTP context. You can find how to mock it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228179/mocking-httpcontextbase-with-moq). Mocking Session property should be straightforward after that.