# Add cookie to Request.Cookies collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, tdd, moq, httpcontext

I am trying to create a wrapper class to process content of HttpContext. I am creating a cookie but unable to add to HttpContext.Request or Response cookies collection.

I am using Moq.
Also I am using MvcMockHelp from the following link:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx

When I try to add to Cookies collection in my following code:

```
        HttpContextBase c1 = MvcMockHelpers.FakeHttpContext();
        HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("userInfo");
        aCookie.Values["userName"] = "Tom";
        c1.Request.Cookies.Add(aCookie);    <------ Error here
```

I get the following error on the 4th line of code c1.Request.Cookies.Add(aCookie);

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have also tried instantiating context object as follows but still no luck

```
HttpContextBase c = MvcMockHelpers.FakeHttpContext
             ("~/script/directory/NAMES.ASP?city=irvine&state=ca&country=usa");
```

I see that Cookies collection inside Request is NULL. How do I instantiate it?

I have also tried the following but no luck.

```
c1.Request.Cookies["userName"].Value = "Tom";
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Check to see if Cookies is null, if so, instantiate it.

Comment: I am unable to instantiate Cookies.. can I get sample to instantiate c1.Request.Cookies code if possible?

Comment: Can you instantiate using this constructor: `FakeHttpContext(string url)` instead? Passing the requesting url; maybe it will help instantiate your `Request` object.

Comment: Yes I have tried..still no luck

Comment: Moses your comment c1.Request.Cookies["someName"] = aCookie; is invalid

Comment: Is Request null as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225511/setting-properties-on-a-mocked-httpcontextbase - this might help

Comment: this article solved it for me... http://blog.paulhadfield.net/2010/09/mocking-httpcookiecollection-in.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at Hansleman's code, the `Request` property is created as a `Mock`, however, the properties of that mock aren't setup, so that's why `Cookies` is null, and you can't set it, as it's a read-only property.

You have two options:

1. Setup the mock of the `Cookies` property in the `FakeHttpContext()` 
   method, or
2. If you don't want to do that, say you're referencing the library directly, then you can simply reconstitute the mocked `HttpRequestBase` from the `HttpContextBase` you have access to, like so:

   ```
   [Test]
   public void SetCookie()
   {
     var c1 = MvcMockHelpers.FakeHttpContext();
     var aCookie = new HttpCookie("userInfo");
     aCookie.Values["userName"] = "Tom";

     var mockedRequest = Mock.Get(c1.Request);
     mockedRequest.SetupGet(r => r.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
     c1.Request.Cookies.Add(aCookie);

     Debug.WriteLine(c1.Request.Cookies["userInfo"].Value);
   }
   ```

   `Mock.Get(object)` will return you the Mock, then you can setup you cookies on it and use it.

In general you can recreate an `Object` into its `Mock` by using the static method `Get(MockedThing.Object)`

Comment: Sorry for the 'a', I can't see how to have a code block follow directly from a list.

Comment: The code is only for part 2 of the list, so it *should* be part of it, which is accomplished by indenting 8 spaces instead of 4.